# Car Sat Outside

Tags: ford, maintenance

My car has sat outside and unstarted for about 6 months in my yard, the part I was waiting on has finally arrived. Is there any services that I should have done to my full-size car while I have it in the shop?

Answer (score 2):

After 6 months the battery is probably flat and might be damaged if it was really completely drained. I'd recommend to hook up a charger and see if the battery still stores any charge.

Also the tires will have flat spots from sitting so long. If they still had enough air in them the flat spots (bumpy ride) will dissappear after a short while, but if a tire went flat it will be damaged and needs to be replaced.